# jQuery Attribute Contains Selector

Tags: jquery

I have a set of divs eg:

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="uct_attr" data-tags="one two three four">stuff</div>
 <div class="uct_attr" data-tags="three four">stuff</div>
 <div class="uct_attr" data-tags="one three five">stuff</div>
 <div class="uct_attr" data-tags="one two six">stuff</div>
 <div class="uct_attr" data-tags="four five six">stuff</div>
</div?
```

How do I perform and action on the ones that match my query and another on the ones that dont? Keeping in mind I one wish to match one of the words in the attribute data-tags

eg:

```
// if match 'one'
$('.wrapper .uct_attr[data-tags="one"]').doMatch();
// the rest that didn't match 'one'
$('.wrapper .uct_attr[data-tags!="one"]').doNotMatch();
```

Issue I think is there are multipul tags in that attribute.

Any help on this would be great.

C

Comment: You are so close: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Comment: how does that work for the `!=`

Comment: See my answer to see how to negate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple enough: Use the [member-of-a-whitespace-delimited-list](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors) selector.

```
var $els = $(".wrapper .uct_attr");
$els.filter("[data-tags~='one']").doMatch();
$els.not("[data-tags~='one']").doNotMatch();
```

Comment: perfect thanks!! But what if I wanted to match one of multipul tags:
eg: `[data-tags~='one three six']` any of these could match.

Comment: `[data-tags~="one"], [data-tags~="three"], [data-tags~="six"]`. CSS is not always concise. ;)

Answer (score 0):

not selector

```
$('.wrapper').find('div').not('.uct_attr[data-tags="one"]').doNotMatch();
```

Comment: `:not` is the CSS selector. There is also the `.not()` jquery method.

Comment: You're still using the *attribute equals* selector. The O.P.'s question is about matching a member of a whitespace-delimited list.

Answer (score 0):

To match a word in an attribute, use the ~= operator as defined here: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/

```
// if match 'one'
$('.wrapper .uct_attr[datatags~="one"]').doMatch();
// the rest that didn't match 'one'
$('.wrapper .uct_attr').not('[datatags~="one"]').doNotMatch();
```

Comment: "data-" is W3C requirement for non-standard html attribute names.